# Where does the $1/c$ come from in the four-gradient?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

Is this just to ensure the units are length, as they will be in the remaining spacial gradient?

$$\partial^{\mu}=\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial}{\partial t},-\nabla \end{pmatrix}$$

and if so, is the reason we can just stick the speed of light in here (as we do with the four-position) because it is invariant under Lorentz transformations?

Comment: yes, it is.....

Comment: Better to ask than guess.

Comment: I agree. I added the dots to reach the min character limit. It didn't express exhasperation, in case that's what you thought.

Comment: Why does your 3-gradient have a negative sign? The signs are more important than the $c$’s! Physicists usually just use units with $c=1$, and put them back into the final result (by dimensional analysis) if necessary

Comment: @Prahar Ah that's fair.

Comment: @G.Smith The formula in my question just comes from Wikipedia, the gradient is negative there: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector#Four-gradient

Comment: @Charlie: Your WP link is to a definition of the upper-index version of the operator, but your question is talking about the lower-index version.

Comment: The index placement matters, as I believe you discovered in a previous question. It is $dx^\mu$ and $\partial_\mu$ that have all-positive components; $dx_\mu$ and $\partial^\mu$ have either 3 positive and 1 negative component or vice versa, depending on your metric convention,

Comment: You're right, I assumed the wrong index without thinking, I have modified the question and the index is now in the correct place.

Comment: It’s OK now, but keep in mind that an upper index is “less natural” than a lower one on a derivative, at least in my opinion. The only time I ever write an upper index on a derivative is when it is being contracted. This may be a personal idiosyncracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, this is purely for dimensional convenience and because c is invariant. Answer credit to [Prahar](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/8821/prahar).

Answer (score 1):

Relativists don't normally use units with $c\ne 1$. If you're using a book that uses this convention, then be aware that it's just their convention. The convention probably doesn't mean much in isolation; to make sense of it, you would probably have to look as well at what other conventions they use in the placement of their factors of $c$. Among people who don't take $c=1$, there are various ways of handling this. Some people put $c$'s in the metric, some in the definition of the displacement vector but not in the metric, etc.

The minus sign just seems like a mistake to me. It would occur in the upper-index version of the operator, $\partial^\mu$, if you're using the $+---$ signature. But it should not be there in the definition of $\partial_\mu$.

Comment: You're right, I have taken that formula for Wikipedia where they just denote it $\partial$, I have corrected it.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain what they think is wrong?

Comment: I didn't down vote but you did write down "The minus sign seems like a mistake to me". :)

Comment: It would have been a mistake in the way I originally wrote it.